# Вывод в консоль JavaScript onclick почему пропадает?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, javascript-events

```
Кнопка <li><a onclick="display(1)" href="">Show 1</a></li>    

<script type="text/javascript">
        var msg = document.getElementById("homework-message");
        var s= 1;
        function display (val){

            s = val;
            console.log(s);

        }

    </script>
```

Почему сообщение стирается из консоли после нажатия, как сделать, чтобы оно оставалось?
Как сделать это без JQuery?

Comment: Потому что после клика по ссылке происходит переход на другую страницу по этой самой ссылке

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У Вас перегружается страница при клике по ссылке c `href=""`.

```js
var s = 1;

function display(event, val) {
  event.preventDefault();
  s = val;
  console.log(s);
}
```

```html
<li><a onclick="display(event, 1)" href="">Show 1</a></li>
```

Answer (score 2):

Просто вставь якорь # в href и не будет перегружатся

```js
    var msg = document.getElementById("homework-message");
    var s= 1;
    function display (val){
        s = val;
        console.log(s);
    }
```

```html
<li><a onclick=display(1) href="#">Show 1</a></li>
```